# Navigating to the first component in a stack navigator with params doesn't work

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a component within a StackNavigator that I always want to pass params to. This doesn't seem to work if my component is the first component loaded in a StackNavigator. Here's some code that illustrates the problem.

- I start in component A.
- I press the button to navigate to component B.
- In the logs you can see that component B is loaded twice. The first time it's loaded without params.

  Android SDK built for x86: rendering with: undefined

  Android SDK built for x86: rendering with: ►{data:"from A"}
- Also if you click the device back button it goes back to the screen with undefined params.

So there are two issues:

1. I only navigated once, but I have to go back twice to get back to where I was.
2. My component is loaded with no params even though I navigated with params.

Here's the code running in an expo snack: https://snack.expo.io/@bdzim/navigate-to-tab-from-parent

```
class A extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Button
          title="This is A. Press to go to B"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(
            'B',  { data: 'from A' }
            )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class B extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log('rendering with: ', this.props.navigation.state.params)
    let params = JSON.stringify(this.props.navigation.state.params)
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>
          params: {params}
        </Text>
        <Button
          title="This is.. B! Press to go to A"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('A')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const Stacks = StackNavigator({ B })
const Tabs = TabNavigator({ A, Stacks });
```